# "That was to become a pattern for every new instructor I was to meet"

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing a passage:

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That was to become a pattern for every new instructor I was to have/meet.

For some reason I am feeling a bit uncertain about having two "be to do" phrases in a single clause. Does this sentence sound stilted? What if I were to change it to:

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That was to become a pattern for every new instructor I had/met.

Comment: is "to be become" a typo? you don't need the *be* in there.

Comment: @Mixolydian Yes! The sentences were extracted and slightly modified from my writing, and unfortunately a typo was introduced in the process. Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the second example is better than the first (the first does sound stilted). But I would also argue that the second sentence (in either case) doesn't add any new information - it sounds redundant. I think the first sentence alone expresses the idea that there was a pattern to what instructors asked you about. You might want to say something more like:

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. After a while, I noticed a pattern.

Here, the second sentence is about *you* noticing the repetitive questions. If this is what you want to bring attention to, I think this is a better way to phrase it.

Comment: +1 I am not sure about "I noticed a pattern" though. In my understanding that implies the hobby questions were incidental. I actually wanted to say those questions were bound to occur. I just didn't understand that until later.

Answer (score 1):

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That **was to become** a pattern for every new instructor I **was to have**.

There is nothing ungrammatical about this sentence, but I can understand why you might want to avoid the repetition of the verb form.

While your proposed change is also fine, I can suggest an alternative:

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That was to become a pattern for all of my new instructors.

This replaces *every* with *all* (*each* is another possibility), thereby allowing you to simply remove the verb at the end of the sentence altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase it one of these 2 ways:

> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That became a pattern for [every new / each] instructor I met.
>
> Every new instructor would ask about my hobbies. That was to become a pattern for [every new / each] instructor I [was to / would] meet [or "met"].

I'd use the first one if I am talking about a pattern that I noticed at the time when I was meeting other instructors (in the past) that I am writing about.

I'd use the second if I am only noticing the pattern in retrospect, at the time of writing.

Or what about:

> Every new instructor *asked about* my hobbies. It became a pattern [or some more explicit wording like "a standard conversational opening"] with every instructor I was to meet